# insert before first and after last

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello how can I insert `before` my first and `after` my last? Here is the code:

```
    $pagerT.find('span.page-number:first').append($previousT);  
    $pagerT.find('span.page-number:last').append($nextT);
```

Basically I want to append the variables before my `first` and `after` my last. How can I append them?

Comment: Perhaps you want `.prepend()` in one of those statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `.append();` You can use `.after();` or `.before();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.before()` and `.after()`

```
$pagerT.find('span.page-number:first').before($previousT);  
$pagerT.find('span.page-number:last').after($nextT);
```

http://api.jquery.com/before/
http://api.jquery.com/after/